# R: How to remove rows and add the value of a variable to the previous row as a comma separated value?

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows:

```
col1    col2
a        1
a        2
b        1
b        3
c        4
```

I want the output as follows:

```
col1    col2
a        1,2
b        1,3
c        4
```

How is it possible in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'col1' and `paste` the 'col2' with `collapse=','` option.  A convenient wrapper would be `toString`.  This can be done with any of the aggregate by group functions.  For example, with `data.table`, we convert 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`) and use the logic as described above

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(col2 = toString(col2)), by = col1]
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(col2~col1, df1, FUN=toString)
```

If you need a `list` output for 'col2'

```
aggregate(col2~col1, df1, FUN=I)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(col1) %>% 
     summarise(col2= toString(col2))
```

Comment: bow to master but which of this is fast and memory efficient

Comment: @VigneshKalai Thanks for the comments.  `aggregate` would be slow for big datasets.  I think both `dplyr` and `data.table` performs similar though I give some edge to `data.table` (not benchmarked though)

Comment: @VigneshKalai, Don't take offence, but instead of asking which approach would be fast and memory efficient on different questions, you can try to explore this on your own. Please take a look at the `microbenchmark` package, and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to understand how to generate simulated datasets. Then with these simulated datasets, run benchmarks to come to your own conclusions. Doing so would also help you understand R and common packages better.

Comment: Thank @AnandaMahto it really helped a lot and it is in no way an offense then how would I learn if don't do the dirty works